# What is a branch in Taylor polynomial (for someone with knowledge only in first-year calculus)?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I know that there has already many definitions of a branch, in the context of Taylor polynomial. Can someone describe to me, in a simplier term for someone with knowledge only in first-year calculus, what a branch actually is? For instance, let say I have the following equation:

$$y = \frac{1}{\sqrt x}$$

Is the branch point $x=0$ and $x = \infty$? If the point of expansion for a Taylor series is at the branch, how likely will the approximation fail?

Comment: Can you state at least one of these many definitions of a branch?

Comment: Definitions usually involve complex numbers which I do not have knowledge of. Is the knowledge of complex numbers necessary for the understanding of branch, with terms in a function that are all real.

Comment: I am no analyst for sure, but branching phenomena is best seen in the complex plane.  Someone else may have a good real example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation $y^2=x$ has two solutions, $y=\sqrt x$ and $y=-\sqrt x$. These two solutions may be thought of as the two branches of the functional inverse of squaring, and they come together (at any rate, their graphs come together) at zero, the branch point. The question of behavior of the Taylor series at $x=0$ does not arise, since the functions are not differentiable at $x=0$ (so a fortiori there is no Taylor expansion at $x=0$).

But most of the time, I'm afraid you do need complex numbers to see what a branch point is, e.g., I don't think there's any way to explain branches of the logarithm without bringing in the complex plane.